# Angular routing back to same URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Hi I'm in the URL `http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/message`, now usecase is I should be able to navigate to particular url by typing route manually in the address bar.
So I need to navigate it to `http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/application-management`, so when I type url `http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/application-management` in address bar it reloads back to `http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/message` not sure why

So in message component I'm checking for /application-management in ngonInit

```
 this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationStart | null) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log('event', event.url);
        /* if (event.url === '/application-management') {
         this.router.navigate(['/application-management']);
        } */
      }
    });
```

But I'm not even getting this console, it simply reloads back to /message.
Need an help on this

Comment: please be more Descriptive, the information is not enough to understand the issue. 
1. please Create sample app which illustrate the issue on StackBlitz Or
2. provide information such as , Route Guard if your app has any , Route Code of Your Module , etc....

Answer (score 1):

Routing is usually done in a RoutingModule. Without knowing your RoutingModule, we cannot help you. If you did not setup custom Modules, it should be called app-routing.module.ts

Here you can read more about how to use Angular Router: https://angular.io/guide/router